# Using Ruby to extract an array of emails from a string that contain names, spaces, and emails

Tags: ruby, regex

The string is very long and contains first names, last names, many spaces and emails. Sometimes names are missing. I'm trying to extract all the emails into an array with a Ruby script. How would I accomplish that?

I found this as the best regex:

```
^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$
```

My string looks something like:

```
"first name last name       abc@hotmail.com  firstname def@gmail.com"
```

How do I create a function that loops through the string and pushes emails into an array?

Answer (score 0):

An email could not have space, so you could use the regex `/\S+@\S+/`:

```
irb(main):004:0> "first name last name       abc@hotmail.com  firstname def@gmail.com".scan(/\S+@\S+/)
=> ["abc@hotmail.com", "def@gmail.com"]
```

`\S` matches the non blank char.